# vi replace visual mode selection with clipboard

Tags: linux, bash

I know that this question has probably already been answered but I can't find it.

Here is what I want to do, imagine I have `world` in my clipboard.

And my file looks like :

```
Hello guys
```

I want to replace `guys` by `world`.

I know that `:%s/guys/world/g` would work but my section is actually huge.

I would like to select my selection with `v` (visual mode) then when I have the proper selection highlighted, paste my clipboard. I tried `p` it's not working.

Any help ?

Comment: Tip: never say "it's not working".  Always describe what happened so we have some info to go on.

Comment: Does it have to be in vi ? There are some ways to do it in command line, using for instancece sed.

Comment: @Gary_W, it replaced the selected text by nothing. Cedric, yes it has to, I know sed

Comment: @EtienneHerlaut Your version must not support it, worked for me.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this on gvim 8.0.2.  This post explains how to do it: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/337cxj/yankpaste_tofrom_system_clipboard/

From that post:

Firstly, execute the command

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

If it returns 1 you're good to go, otherwise check if your distro has a more full-featured vim package (or compile it yourself)

To copy to the clipboard, enter either visual, visual-block , or visual-line mode, select your text and press the sequence (not combo):

```
"+y
```

and your text is ready to be pasted into any other program or window.

Additionally you can execute that sequence in normal mode, however its behavior is not ideal (in my opinion). It yanks the remaining characters on the current line, after the cursor plus the characters on the next line up until the column of the cursor. Decent if your cursor is at column 0, otherwise kind of annoying.

By replacing the 'y' with a 'p' you get the same behavior you would expect from just 'p' in normal mode, however pasted from the system clipboard. On a modern setup, this is probably not as useful, as we have Ctrl-Shift-v, but I can certainly think of some use-cases for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the normal paste command of terminal `ctrl+shift+v`? It works for me after selecting content through `v`.